# tableau adjust marks size using number

Tags: tableau-api

In Marks, click Size and there pops a slider where I can adjust the size of a shape. But how to accurately control the size, is there some property with numbers to accurately control it? I have two sheets to show something similar and I want to display exactly the same sized shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure 'sizes' are the same across two worksheets, I'd suggest snapping the 'size' setting to the center on both, as this is the easiest option to select. You can then use a measure to set the size, if this is desirable, and then the difference in size will be relative on both worksheets.

There isn't a numerical value override for the size slider.

Answer (score 1):

Ben is correct, there isn't yet a numerical value override for the slider. You can use parameters with Min/Max/Sum etc. and a variable to somewhat change the sizes but they have to have multiple entries per line.  It is unfortunate that Tableau still doesn't get that people want both a 'relative' sizing system that uses numbers from the dataset and a 'static' sizing system that allows for shapes to be set to '11px' or something along those lines.  Yes, you can control that kind of in the dashboard with a vertical and fill entire box etc; but that doesn't address the very real scenario where you want a user to be able to re-size on the fly. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today. Very annoying. Need to keep shapes the same size across all worksheets and therefore same on dashboard.